# TableView stuck with First Responder and Exit in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I was editing my storyboard and at some stage I don't know how my tableview start to show on top of my table view controller instead inside it as show in the screenshot of my xcode!

It seems to be something wrong with the my table view as I can add another tablew view from the library and it add fine, also I can't move my table view to another table view controller

[image]

I try everything and I can't place it back where it belong.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing content view! Grab UIView and put it inside Container Nurseries.

[image: storyboard]

Then you'll be able to drag your Table View a drop it inside the container view.

Comment: It doesn't let me to!

Comment: Then may be the easier way will be to create new UIViewController and place your table view there. But I tried this particular situation in my xcode and it works.

Comment: It also does not go inside the new UITableViewController, I try delete the existent one and place this one inside, nothing work! I never saw that before

Comment: Could you share entire project? I would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I can't there are lots of addresses from your API that is not public all over the code! :/ If was my own project I wouldn't mind